# How to show random gallery in slideshow (no random images)

Tags: javascript, xml, slideshow, carousel

I want to make a slideshow carousel that displays the images from a gallery xml file.

But I have 13 xml file gallery's and I want to random display the gallery's.
I'm thinking about using the the elastislide carousel  [a link] (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/)

hope it is possible im making it for my exam project.

Comment: So you want to randomly pick one of the 13 XML files to load?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide code for any issue you're having with this?

Answer (score 0):

Exam project, so no direct answer :) but here is set of steps that should guide you on how to go about doing this.

1. Use [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function of jQuery to load xml file.
2. On each load you can [parse an xml using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), just like an html.
3. Parse all XML files and create and array of url of image from them.
4. Now you can use a random number generator seeded with current time, to pick an image url from array.
5. Then use any carousel plugin to display them.

If you need to pick an xml file randomly. Create an array with file names, then use same technique to pick random names and load when with .ajax() in jQuery.